# Adding two probability density function

Tags: evolutionary-algorithm, probability-density

I'm working with a evolutionary algorithm and I'm trying to generate new population using probability density function. We have many classical individual(Xij) and his fitness( f(Xij) ), to have probabilities for each of them, normalize fitness for instance I have Xij with probability 0.10 and I can get pdf.
During iterations I will have many pdf's, I want to save information of last pdf in the actual pdf. I have tried adding but I think it's not the best choice. What would you recommend?

[Example of pdf's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtqgN.png)

PD: you can watch peaks of the pdf's in the picture.

Comment: Are these  really pdfs (functions which are integrated to give probabilities of random variables lying in intervals)?  I'm not really sure what you are asking about. What are these functions supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question I will have to make some assumptions:

- You have individuals Xij
- You have individual fitness or scores f(Xij)
- You normalize the score/fitness to a probability density function by applying a function to the fitness. In other words: pdf(Xij) = g(f(Xij)
- You require persistence in the pdf to allow selection of specimen that performed well over several iterations.

I would either use a running average of the fitness score and then normalize the averaged score; or use a running average of the normalized score for a new pdf.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I have finished it some time ago.